# How to prevent re-render of parent when child dispatches changes to global state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Premise**:
i have a screen component, an accordion component, and that component has subitem components. these subitem components change global state to handle their checked/unchecked state.

as a sibling to the accordions, i have a component that reads the global state to display the checked-count, so the screen component is accessing the global state to decouple the state from being explicitly called by the checked-count component

**Problem**:
when the accordion sub-item dispatches changes to global state, the accordion re-renders, thus messing with the expanded/collapsed state.

This is happening because the screen component thats accessing the global state is re-rendering. since i want to continue to dole out this global state from the screen, and avoid explicitly accessing global state inside the component (effort to make it re-usable), how can i prevent the screen from re-rendering when the sub-item updates global state, but also propagate those changes for the sub-item & checked-count component to re-render?

**Screen**:

```
export function List() {
  const{ state: { checkedItems }, dispatch } = useData()
  const [queue, setQueue] = useState([
      {id: '1'},
      {id: '2'},
      {id: '3'}
  ]);

  const setChecked = (id, shouldCheck) => {
    const type = shouldCheck ? 'checkItem' : 'uncheckItem'
    console.log('[ DISPATCH ] id:', id, 'type:', type)

    dispatch({type, payload: id})
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Accordion>
        { 
          items
            .filter(item => item.type === 3)
            .map(item => useMemo(() => <AccordionSubItem item={item} onPress={setChecked}/>))
        }
      </Accordion>
        
      <CheckedCount indicator={checkedItems.length + ' selected'} visible={checkedItems.length > 0}>/        
    </View>
  )
};
```

**AccordionSubItem**:

```
export default AccordionSubItem = ({ item, onPress}) => {
  const { state: {checkedItems} } = useData()

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.dataWrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{item.subtitle}</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(item.id, !checkedItems.includes(item.id))} style={styles.dataWrapper}>
      <Checkbox
        status={checkedItems.includes(item.id) ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
        color="white"
      />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Note: the `dispatch` and `state` youre seeing is not the typical redux setup. but ultimately, state is still returned by a reducer, and dispatch is an async function

How can i prevent the screen re-render but also ensure the sub-item component and checked-count component update their state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's totally ok that your `List` component rerenders when it's inner state is changed. The problem here is your `AccordionsubItem`s are not keyed. I believe keying them should fix the problem:

```ts
<Accordion>
    {items
        .filter(item => item.type === 3)
        .map(item => <AccordionSubItem key={item.id} item={item} onPress={setChecked}/>)
    }
</Accordion>
```

I've removed the `useMemo` here since it doesn't look to give any advantage in this place.

Comment: the project im working on actually had the navigation components poorly structured. they were creating nav components with screens nested inside, big mess. once i fixed that it cleared up my issue. but this is still valid, i had just begun implementing this and hadnt added keys yet.